# PGP encryption of large files on Azure Blob

Tags: c#, encryption, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, pgp

I am using PGPCore to encrypt/decrypt files in an Azure Function. Files are stored in a Blob Block Container.
Encryption works fine, nothing to mention.

Decryption instead is giving me a few headaches.

Ideally, I would like to use the `OpenWrite/Read` methods on BlobBlockClient in order to avoid downloading and encrypting in memory. I was hoping to use something like this:

```
await using var sourceStream = await sourceBlobClient.OpenReadAsync();

var destBlobClient = destContainer.GetBlockBlobClient(command.SourcePath);
await using var destStream = await destBlobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true);

await using var privateKey = _pgpKeysProvider.GetPrivate();
using var pgp = new PgpCore.PGP();

await pgp.DecryptStreamAsync(sourceStream, destStream, privateKey.Key, privateKey.Passphrase);
```

I am however experiencing a few issues:

1. `OpenReadAsync()` returns a non-seekable stream, which apparently cannot be used by `DecryptStreamAsync()`. To mitigate this, I'm downloading the blob in memory, which I honestly wanted to avoid:

   ```
   await using var sourceStream = new MemoryStream();
   await sourceBlobClient.DownloadToAsync(sourceStream);
   sourceStream.Position = 0;
   ```

   Is there any way to fix this?
2. even if I bite the bullet and download the encrypted file into a `MemoryStream`, `DecryptStreamAsync()` is returning an empty stream. The only solution I have found so far is to decrypt to another `MemoryStream` and then upload this one to the Blob Container. Which I also wanted to avoid. I even tried to get rid of the `using` and manually call Dispose() on the streams, just in case there was any potential issue there. No luck.

Small files aren't a problem, I'm concerned about big ones (eg. 4gb or more)

Any advice?

Comment: If you want to decrypt file in Azure function, I think you can use the Azure function blob trigger, it will return blob content as stream : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage

Comment: The problem is not how to retrieve the blob stream. The problem is how to avoid copying it entirely in memory when decrypting and uploading back.

Comment: If so you can get blob content on range : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetostream?view=azure-dotnet-legacy

Comment: sorry, but I fail to see how this could help me

Comment: Can you help me understand what you are trying to avoid and why?  Avoid having any of the bytes in memory?  Or all of them at once?   I've got a sample implementation I could share that streams the remote blob into an Azure function cryptosteam, which is also simultaneously streaming (writing) to a destination stream (blob, etc..).

Comment: I am trying to avoid two things:
- downloading the blob into a memory stream
- performing the encryption into another memory stream and upload it

Comment: Do you have to use PGP encryption on the whole 4GB file? Not even PGP did that. It created a random key for use with a symmetric encryption algorithm and then used asymmetric encryption only on the key itself. This way an encryption algorithm more suitable for large files could be used.